# How to make two arrays into a single key-value pair dictionary to pass to HTML from JS

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dictionary, getelementbyid

I am making a program in which the user presses a button to get a random question and then can press another button to get the answer. I wanted to make a dictionary in JS to contain the questions and answers but couldn't figure out how to do so, so I opted for two arrays; one with the questions and one with the answers. This method works fine but I know there must be a more correct way to accomplish the same thing with a dictionary containing key-value pairs. Here is the JavaScript code:

```
const questions = Array(
"Question one",
"Question two",
"Question three",
);

const answers = Array(
"Answer one",
"Answer two",
"Answer three",
);

function randomQuestion() {
  const len = answers.length;
  const rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
  document.getElementById('randomQuestion').value = questions[rnd];
  document.getElementById('randomAnswer').value = answers[rnd];
}
```

Thank you in advance. I am new to coding so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Just use an array of objects where each one is having the properties question and answer.. [{question:’q1’,answer:’a1’},{question:’q2’,answer:’a2’}]

Comment: Why a map object (dictionary), why not an array of tuples `[['question1','answer1'].…]` or QA objects `[{question: 'question1', answer: 'answer1'},…]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Melih's answer is correct but without using classes just do this:

```
const questions = [
{ question: "Question one", answer: "Answer one" },
{ question: "Question two", answer: "Answer two" },
{ question: "Question three", answer: "Answer three" },
];

function randomQuestion() {
  const len = questions.length;
  const rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
  document.getElementById('randomQuestion').value = questions[rnd].question;
  document.getElementById('randomAnswer').value = questions[rnd].answer;
}
```

Comment: The only change that would need to be made would be that it should be questions.length. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

```
class QuestionAnswer {
  QA;
  constructor() {
    this.QA = [];
  }

  AddQuestion(question, answer) {
    this.QA.push({ question: question, answer: answer });
  }

  GetQuestion(index) {
    return this.QA[index];
  }
}

const qa = new QuestionAnswer();
qa.AddQuestion("Q1", "A1");
qa.AddQuestion("Q2", "A2");
qa.AddQuestion("Q3", "A3");

const q1 = qa.GetQuestion(1);
console.log(`Question: ${q1.question} - Answer: ${q1.answer}`);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).